# Cannot connect to a specific wifi on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking

I cannot connect to a wifi. I can only use internet from mobile hotspot. I have Qualcomm Atheros AR5BWB222 as a network adappter on my laptop with ath09k driver. Also I am using dual boot with windows 10. I would be really grateful for any an advice. I have already tried a lot of approaches and nothing worked.

UPDATE:

```
lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0034] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:0802]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k

rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

sudo iwlist scan
       Cell 02 - Address: XXXX
                Channel:2
                Frequency:2.417 GHz (Channel 2)
                Quality=52/70  Signal level=-58 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"XXXX"
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                          18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                Mode:Master
                Extra:tsf=00000065a7c77857
                Extra: Last beacon: 36ms ago
                IE: Unknown: 00107072616E65742E637A2F31312E313331
                IE: Unknown: 010882848B961224486C
                IE: Unknown: 030102
                IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                IE: Unknown: 32040C183060
                IE: Unknown: 2D1A6C0016FF00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 3D1602000400000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: WPA Version 1
                    Group Cipher : CCMP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : CCMP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101000003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                IE: Unknown: 0B05010015127A
                IE: Unknown: DD07000C4300000000
```

I found out, I can not connect only to my home wifi (only with windows) but to other wifis I can.

Comment: Let's start by identifying your exact device. Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and also: `rfkill list all` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I updated the post. How is it possible I cannot connect to my home wifi but can connect to others?

Comment: How is your home network set up? Please show us: `sudo iwlist scan` Only show your own network, that you cannot connect to, and redact the MAC address with XXXX. We suspect that a few tweaks in the router may fix it.

Comment: I updated output/information about the network I cannot connect to from iwlist scan on post. I have also tried to connect my laptop to wifi with Ethernet cabel and it did not also worked.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me: https://askubuntu.com/a/1277071/35310 I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Answer (score 0):

Please check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Reboot and tell us if there is any improvement.

Comment: How do I configure WPA2-AES authentication? I do not even have this option in wifi settings

Comment: I have defaultly selected WPA & WPA2 Personal, then there is WPA Enterprise and others but not AES

Comment: I set the variable REGDOMAIN to my regional domain, then I reboot the router and finally ubuntu. Still cannot connect. 
And I am not sure, if it is capable of N speeds and do not know how to configure these channels and authentication with WPA-AES :/

Comment: What is the make and model of the router? The configuration may look something like this: https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/wp-content/uploads/2008/02/linksys-wpa2.png

Comment: I figured out partially. My router model is: lib-link BL-WR1100. It has four RJ45 ethernet connectors and one RJ-45 port WAN. If I unplug cabel from port WAN and plug it into the one of the other four ethernet connectors, it works in Ubuntu, but it does not work on windows. But still do not know why.