# Can't connect to a specific WiFi network (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: wireless, password, router

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and I can't connect to a specific wifi network. I have the password and I can connect to it with success in the same laptop with Windows 10 but in ubuntu it stays connecting for a long time then connection failed ,I have tried most of the solutions on the internet and nothing works. I can connect to my mobile hotspot easily. The problem in connecting to my home router only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

open

```
 nm-connection-editor
```

forget all connections and then edit your connection and choose specific band and channel number of your connection

worked for me check for yours

Comment: Worked for me, tried a lot of things from here https://askubuntu.com/q/960691/496677 and https://askubuntu.com/a/622493/496677, didn't know how suddenly I got this issue but I'm glad I wasn't the only one facing this issue.

Comment: Finally for me this solution worked. I just changed the specific band (selected B/G 2.4 GHz instead of automatic, as it was the case of my router), and I left the channel as "automatic", and it worked anyway.